# How placement new can be done on stack

Tags: c++, new-operator, placement-new

Consider the following codes:

```
char mem[sizeof(char)];
void* p = mem;
f = new(p) char;
```

Since the memory for variable mem should be on stack
So, why doesn't this piece of memory get collected automatically in the end.

Comment: Note that this won't work in general: `char mem[sizeof(T)]; new (mem) T();` because `T` may have alignment restrictions that `mem` did not satisfy.

Answer (score 9):

The memory IS collected automatically.

But the destructor won't be called automatically.  When you use placement `new`, you should pair that with a manual destructor call.  For `char` this doesn't really matter of course, since the destructor is trivial.

Comment: Thank you, Ben. It really helps me to figured out some questions about placement new.